# How to get values of other columns and put it in a specific column? (in same rows)

Tags: python, string, pandas, concatenation

I have 3 columns with the same name

```
   PUESTO       PUESTO       PUESTO
   MEDICO       AYUDANTE     AYUDANTE II
   ENFERMERO    nan          nan
   JARDINERO    nan          nan
   INGENIERO    nan          nan
   METEOROLOGO  OBSERVADOR   nan
   ABOGADO      PRACTICANTE  PRACTICANTE II
   CONTADOR     PRACTICANTE  PRACTICANTE II
```

I want to get the information of the 2nd and 3rd column and put it in the 1rst column like this:

```
   PUESTO       

   MEDICO
   AYUDANTE
   AYUDANTE II    

   ENFERMERO           

   JARDINERO            

   INGENIERO              

   METEOROLOGO
   OBSERVADOR     

   ABOGADO        
   PRACTICANTE
   PRACTICANTE II

   CONTADOR       
   PRACTICANTE
   PRACTICANTE II
```

So i tried this:

```
df.iloc[:,1] = df.iloc[:,1].str.cat(df.iloc[:,2:3], sep ="\n")
```

But if there is a None value (nan) in any of the columns, the 1rst column is filled with nans. And i don't want that.

So i tried this:

```
for i in df.iloc[:,2:3]!=None:
   df.iloc[:,1] = df.iloc[:,1].str.cat(df.iloc[:,2:3], sep ="\n")
```

But this fill with nans the first column (if there is a nan value in any column) like the first slice of code that i showed.
I will appreciate if you can help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, use stack:

```
df.stack(dropna=False).fillna('')
```

Output:

```
0  PUESTO              MEDICO
   PUESTO.1          AYUDANTE
   PUESTO.2       AYUDANTE II
1  PUESTO           ENFERMERO
   PUESTO.1                  
   PUESTO.2                  
2  PUESTO           JARDINERO
   PUESTO.1                  
   PUESTO.2                  
3  PUESTO           INGENIERO
   PUESTO.1                  
   PUESTO.2                  
4  PUESTO         METEOROLOGO
   PUESTO.1        OBSERVADOR
   PUESTO.2                  
5  PUESTO             ABOGADO
   PUESTO.1       PRACTICANTE
   PUESTO.2    PRACTICANTE II
6  PUESTO            CONTADOR
   PUESTO.1       PRACTICANTE
   PUESTO.2    PRACTICANTE II
```

Answer (score 1):

From you expected result I see that you want to concatenate not only
data from second and third column, but from **all three** columns
(and save the concatenation result in the first column).

To do it, you can run:

```
df.iloc[:,0] = df.fillna('').apply(lambda row: row.str.cat(sep='\n').strip(), axis=1)
```

The advantage of my solution over the other is that the result has
a **single** element resulting from each row (not a sequence of 3 elements).

When you `print(df)`, the result may be a bit misleading:

```
                                  PUESTO       PUESTO          PUESTO
0          MEDICO\nAYUDANTE\nAYUDANTE II     AYUDANTE     AYUDANTE II
1                              ENFERMERO          NaN             NaN
2                              JARDINERO          NaN             NaN
3                              INGENIERO          NaN             NaN
4                METEOROLOGO\nOBSERVADOR   OBSERVADOR             NaN
5   ABOGADO\nPRACTICANTE\nPRACTICANTE II  PRACTICANTE  PRACTICANTE II
6  CONTADOR\nPRACTICANTE\nPRACTICANTE II  PRACTICANTE  PRACTICANTE II
```

But to check whether `\n` chars above are **true** *newline* chars, run:

```
for r in df.iloc[:, 0]:
    print(f'{r}\n')
```

i.e. print only the first column, with an empty line between consecutive
elements, and the result will be:

```
MEDICO
AYUDANTE
AYUDANTE II

ENFERMERO

JARDINERO

INGENIERO

METEOROLOGO
OBSERVADOR

ABOGADO
PRACTICANTE
PRACTICANTE II

CONTADOR
PRACTICANTE
PRACTICANTE II
```